# How do I print the promise value from a post request? (ReactJs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, async-await, fetch

I've been trying to figure out how to access the promise value passed back from the POST request, but so far the solutions I've seen on here I can't get my head round how to implement in a functional component not using `.then`.

I've tried `.stringify` and `.text` , but no difference. It's still only console logging the promise.

[image]

Button.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import getResponse from '../Handler/getResponse.jsx'
import getToken from '../Handler/getToken.jsx'
import './Button.css';

const Button = ({selectedIcon}) => {
   const [selected] = selectedIcon;
   const [xappToken] = useState(getToken());
   console.log(xappToken);

   return(
      <div className="buttonBlock">
         <span className="btn">
            <input className="btn-outline" type="button" value="Press Me" onClick={ () => getResponse(xappToken) }/>
         </span>
      </div>
   );
}

export default Button
```

getToken.jsx

```
export default async function getToken(){
   try {
     const response = await axios.post('https://api.artsy.net/api/tokens/xapp_token', {
         client_id: 'some-client-id',
         client_secret: 'some-client-secret'
     });
     console.log(' Returned data:', response.data.token);
     return  response.data.token;
   } catch (e) {
     console.log(` Axios request failed: ${e}`);
     return "Error";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `getToken` is a promise. You can do this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import getResponse from '../Handler/getResponse.jsx'
import getToken from '../Handler/getToken.jsx'
import './Button.css';

const Button = ({selectedIcon}) => {
   const [selected] = selectedIcon;
   const [xappToken, setXappToken] = useState(null);
   useEffect(() => {
     getToken().then(token => setXappToken(token))
   }, [])
   console.log(xappToken)

   return(
      <div className="buttonBlock">
         <span className="btn">
            <input className="btn-outline" type="button" value="Press Me" onClick={ () => getResponse(xappToken) }/>
         </span>
      </div>
   );
}

export default Button
```

Answer (score 0):

if i remember correctly 
since you're getting a promise your gonna have to await the response as well.
you have to json() your response and store it into something else 
then console.log the new result
for example

```
const result = await response.json()
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import getResponse from '../Handler/getResponse.jsx'
import getToken from '../Handler/getToken.jsx'
import './Button.css';

const Button = async ({selectedIcon}) => {
   const [selected] = selectedIcon;
   const [xappToken] = useState(await getToken());
   console.log(xappToken);

   return(
      <div className="buttonBlock">
         <span className="btn">
            <input className="btn-outline" type="button" value="Press Me" onClick={ () => getResponse(xappToken) }/>
         </span>
      </div>
   );
}

export default Button
```

Comment: This will not work. React components cannot return promises

Answer (score 0):

I guess you also need to do an async await in the Button.jsx:

```
    const Button = async ({ selectedIcon }) => {
        const [selected] = selectedIcon;
        const [xappToken] = useState(await getToken());
        console.log(xappToken);
    };
```

Since getToken is well, technically a promise. So you need to do an await before accessing the value of that.